# Eclipse Operation Failure When Using Periods

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

For some reason after I type a period "." my eclipse instance gives me a "Cannot Perform Operation - This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project" Error. I understand the issue, but can't seem to get it working again...

The current project that I'm busy with is a java file imported via Maven.

Eclipse Version:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600

[Java Advanced Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xEHO.png)

Comment: When you type a period... where? In your code? In Maven? In a configuration file? In a path?

Comment: As mentioned this is in Eclipse, so if I type a period anywhere in my java file via the eclipse IDE it gives me that error.

Comment: Are there build errors in the project? Does the error still occur when you remove `.` in the field _Window > Properties: Java > Editor > Content Assist: Auto Activation: Auto activation triggers for Java_?

Comment: @howlger If I disable it there the issue resolves, thanks! The only problem now is that the same error displays when I ctrl+space to auto complete code, I can understand if it was code that isn't native to vanilla Java, but it does it for simple things like System.out

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use? Can you please add a screenshot of _Window > Properties: Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced_ to your question?

Comment: @howlger added to the original post.

Comment: If you select only _Java Type Proposals_ and _Templates_ in the upper area, does the error still occur? If yes, can you find out which one causing the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure you *do* understand the issue. Your source file is not in a path declared to be a source folder. You either need to move it or make the right parent folder a Source Folder on the project's Java Build Path. If Maven imported a source file for some reason that you needed to modify, M2E should have set it up as a source folder.

Comment: @howlger The issue still persists after I make those changes.

Comment: @nitind The project that I'm using is a repo from GitHub.

Comment: Unless you point to the repository, that doesn't add any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both @nitind and @howlger. The issue I had was due to the fact that I had to many "Content Assist" options selected which was causing for an unnecessarily long scroll between content. This coupled with the fact that my project was imported as a Maven project and not a Java project cause the issue.

Because of it not being seen as a Java project, some of the Java "Content Assists" didn't recognize the project, which gave me the error above and because I had so many assists selected it kept giving me the error no matter how many times I scrolled.

I fixed the issue by converting the project back to java type as well as removing all the extra "Control Assist" options.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I just solved it. Thanks

1. First, type " . " (period) on eclipse the error will appear then click the **content assist**
2. Click on Content Assist Settings and you will see " Auto activation triggers for Java ",then delete the " . " (period) click apply to save.